# 500 Internal server error

Tags: files

I have a site running Drupal 7, and hosted on GoDaddy.

I use Filezilla FTP client to upload the files, or do any kind of file management on the server.

When I upload a file, the site shows a 500 error. After 25-30 minutes, the site starts working as usual.

This happens every time I upload a file.

Comment: Can you check the error logs for any errors ?

Comment: I also have checked the error log, but there is no information regarding 500 internal server error

Comment: No. I don't have load balancers. I have installed Boost module. Is it creating a problem ?

Comment: Don't have a solution for you but sounds like cache is keeping the 500 error. Can u use drush on the site and do `drush cc all` after you uploaded a file and seeing the 500? this won't fix it but it might push you in a right direction.

Comment: have you checked [this](http://drupal.org/node/989168) already?

Comment: Check the permissions of your web root folder. Also, try increasing your php memory_limit.

Comment: Do you have mod_security? check also if you have installed suphp?

Answer (score 1):

I have this error number of times while refreshing or uploading modules.
it seems to be a server error. because some time server does not respond.

Comment: I also think so..But this should not happen. Do you have any idea how to fix it

Comment: This [link] (http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html) should be fruitful for you.